# Unable to successfully call captureVisibleTab() despite requesting <all_urls> permissions

Tags: permissions, screenshot

I'm working on a [browser extension for React DOM](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-devtools-experimental). This extension has a "Profiler" UI which measures render performance for React components. I recently added screen captures to this Profiler so that it can show images of the DOM each time React updates it.

To do this, the extension [calls `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-devtools-experimental/blob/ed6e34da8e839bf63edb9085086b4e2567771e46/shells/browser/shared/src/background.js#L126) in response to a request from the DevTools extension UI. (This request is made each time React commits changes to the DOM.)

I've [required the `<all_urls>` permission](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-devtools-experimental/blob/ed6e34da8e839bf63edb9085086b4e2567771e46/shells/browser/chrome/manifest.json#L43) for now, based on [the documentation for this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab), which says:

> You must have the `<all_urls>` permission to use this method. (Alternately, Chrome allows use of this method with the `activeTab` permission and a qualifying user gesture).

(The [Chrome documentation for this API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) doesn't mention either way.)

In my experience, I am able to capture the screen after updates caused by e.g. clicking on an anchor element. However, other types of updates (e.g. "scroll" events, programmatically calling `click()` on an element) fail with an the following error being logged to the background script:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

Is the documentation wrong about this API? Have I defined my permissions incorrect? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused that this works for "click" events given that it doesn't work for e.g. "scroll" events. (Since the `postMessage` calls in between are async, I wouldn't expect the browser to associate a screenshot with a previous click event...)

Comment: It looks like this has something to do with focus. If I click *then* scroll within the window, I am able to capture screenshots of the page. If I scroll with e.g. a track pad while focused on the DevTools panel, I can't capture them.